# Facebook SDK button in android studio

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add a facebook login to my app, in addition to my custom log in.

I added facebook sdk as a module but when I try to add the `Facebook Connect` button I get an error.

```
Error:
 Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.facebook.widget.LoginButton (Open Class, Show Exception)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F040001.
```

Code:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/authButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First it is possible problem of the Eclipse, you just need to rester environment. To see if help.

Secondary, try to use this code snippet to solve problem.

```
if (isInEditMode())
{
    //do something else, as getResources() is not valid.
} else {
    //you can use getResources()
    String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
}
```

Comment: I am using Android Studio, how do I reset the enviorment? @Oleg Gordiichuk